# How to specify different install/uninstall order of .msi packages within a Wix bundle?

Tags: wix, bundle, wix3.6, burn

This is my first Wix bundle so I might not know obvious stuff but I have the following requirement:

If I have a Wix bundle package which inside has a bootstrapper application and two .msi packages (lets call them A and B). I understand that if I put them in a Chain element, they will be installed in that order, in my case I want A to be installed first, then B. However upon uninstalling, I want B to be uninstalled first, than A. Is that possible?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried the default behavior? It might be just what you need.

Comment: Haven't tried it because I cannot yet, I'm a bit early in the bundle's development and knowing the answer (whether it is the default behavior, how can I make it that way or that it is impossible) would determine how I develop my packages further.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you are describing is the default behaviour - if Burn installs A before B, then A will also be uninstalled after B.

The order is defined by the `After` argument of the [`MsiPackage`](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_msipackage.htm) element, which identifies the package that this package should be installed after.  If it is not present then this defaults to the previous element in the parent `Chain`, so that the order of installation is simply the order of the child elements in your `Chain`.